# Can not start Gwt project

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

I am unable to start my gwt program on eclipse. I got the following error and was just hoping someone could point me in the right direction

I have already done a maven update and cleaned my workplace. Nothing changed in regards to code since it was last working

```
Starting Jetty on port 7771
   [WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload{/,file:/C:/Users/Daniel/git/JLimoCore/DriverGWT/src/main/webapp/},C:\Users\Daniel\git\JlimoCore\DriverGWT\src\main\webapp
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.matched(JarScanner.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.matchPatterns(PatternMatcher.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.match(PatternMatcher.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.scan(JarScanner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:493)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
Super Dev Mode starting up
   [WARN] unable to delete 'C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-2477172839670597618.tmp\com.limosys.web.gwt.driver.DriverViewer\compile-1' (skipped)
   [ERROR] unable to create directory: C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-2477172839670597618.tmp\com.limosys.web.gwt.driver.DriverViewer\compile-1
```

Comment: Looks like a zip file broke.

Comment: What is your GWT version?

Comment: You most definitely have a bad JAR file in your war's `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: I am using 2.7. You all were right about the jar file. I did a maven clean/install to fix the bad jar files. thanks for the help